# efficient way to aggregate response in java

Tags: java

i have use case where in particular user might have one or more accounts. 
For each account i have to call rest api and the response from api for one account is something as below.

```
{
    "succ": [
        {
            "ruleCode": "1"
        },
        {
            "ruleCode": "4"
        },
        {
            "ruleCode": "6"
        },
        {
            "ruleCode": "7"
        },
        {
            "ruleCode": "8"
        },
        {
            "ruleCode": "9"
        }
    ],
    "fail": [
        {
            "ruleCode": "2"
        },
        {
            "ruleCode": "3"
        },
        {
            "ruleCode": "5"
        },
        {
            "ruleCode": "6"
        }
    ]
}
```

After running the api for all accounts i need to aggregate the response to see what are the aggregated success rules and failed rules.

I was thinking about using map where key is rulecode and value is either true/false. and when particular rule is succeeded update the value to true.
but i am not sure if that is effetive and best way to do it.

I am looking for ideas on what is the best way to acheive it

Comment: How many rules are there (or will there ever be)? Are rules always either failed or succeeded? Your example contains a rule that is both failed and succeeded (6), is that a typo? Otherwise what should the course of action be for those? How do you want to aggregate rules from different accounts (what's the truth table) ?

Comment: Sorry I meant to add this comment here : The Map solution may not work in a scenario where in account 1 the rule code 2 fails and in account 2 the rule code 2 is a success.

Comment: i have around 18 rules, yes it a typo, for a account, if the rule is in success, it will not be in failure

Comment: map solution will probably work, once the code is success, we will not be updating that key anymore. so end of processing we will have all codes which are succeeded (even once it is success, we assume that rule is success)

Answer (score 0):

I guess it depends on things like the set of rule codes.  What you've shown are small, apparently sequential numbers; if that's consistently what the codes are, then a `List<boolean>` might be a good way to go.  A `Map` would work for any type and set of keys, so more flexible and almost certainly not a "wrong" choice.

Also consider that if you're making a bunch of API calls and processing them asynchronously as they're received, then you need thread-safety either in your data structures or in the code that updates them.

So that suggests that you could use a `List` implemented as `ArrayList` or `Vector`, or a `Map` implemented as `HashMap` or `HashTable`, all as reasonable options.

And here's the thing... it looks like you're dealing with a small set of values.  Even if that's just a sample and the real set is somewhat larger, the question is: how much is it worth fussing over the "most efficient" implementation.  If it's not outrageously inefficient, the odds are the performance of the system will be mostly defined by those remote calls than by which data structure you use to aggregate the results.

Don't over-optimize.  Pick a structure that makes sense and gives you readable, maintainable code, and if/when a performance problem is observed, adjust to address it.

Answer (score 0):

What about something like this? Have a separate `Set` for passed and failed rules:

```
private static class RulesResults {

    private Set<String> passedRules = new HashSet<>();
    private Set<String> failedRules = new HashSet<>();

    /** Merges other RulesResults into this result, mutates this result */
    public void mergeResults(RulesResults other) {
        this.passedRules.addAll(other.passedRules);
        this.failedRules.addAll(other.failedRules);
        this.failedRules.removeAll(this.passedRules);
    }
}
```

Alternatively, if you still want to use `Map`s then you could do this.

```
public Map<String, Boolean> mergeResults(Map<String, Boolean> map1, Map<String, Boolean> map2){
           // combine the streams of results
    return Stream.concat(map1.entrySet().stream(), map2.entrySet().stream())
            .collect(
                // collect to map with collision handling
                Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue,
                    // collision handler: if either are true, map to true, else false
                    (origVal, newVal) -> { return origVal || newVal; }
                )
            );
}
```

Comment: @Praveen how did it go?

Answer (score -1):

For each account you count success rules and add them . For each account if n success rules are there then 9-n failure rules are there.Thus count for all accounts that will result in aggregate .

Comment: For some definition of aggregate, I suppose that's true.  So ok... for 9 accounts I keep counts, and I find that each one had 8 successes.  How many total rules have at least one success?  (Actually even if you could answer that it would be short of the mark; OP implied the need to know *which* rules do/don't have at least one success.)